# OpenCV won't accept large image (over 1 GB) Attempted changing the path variable and it still won't accept the image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

So I am trying to read some very large files into opencv using `cv2.imread(image_path)`. However open cv returns the error "error: (-215:Assertion failed) pixels <= CV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS in function 'cv::validateInputImageSize'".

I have tried using `os.environ["OPENCV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS"] = pow(2,30).__str__()` as suggested in other threads but I still get the same error. I am at a loss as to how to adjust the maximum pixel values, any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I guess the obvious question is *"how many pixels are in your image?"* Try `exiftool YOURIMAGE` and click [edit] and add the output to your question.

Comment: The [following example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58085391/4926757) uses `pow(2,40)`. 2^30 is probably the default limit. Try `pow(2,40)` instead. Make sure `os.environ` is before `import cv2`.